# Property 'serviceBeans' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.Path.limited()Z

Tags: java, spring, web-services, cxf

I'm running into a problem with a combination of Spring 3.0.5 and Apache CXF 2.1. Some dependency seem to be missing or it's a compatibility issue? Can anyone provide any help/pointers?

```
org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'serviceBeans' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.Path.limited()Z
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:102)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:58)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358)


Project dependencies

spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar  
spring-asm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar  
spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar  
spring-context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar  
spring-context-support-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar  
spring-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar  
spring-expression-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar  
spring-jdbc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar  
spring-jms-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar  
spring-orm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar  
spring-security-config-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar  
spring-security-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar  
spring-security-core-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar  
spring-test-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar  
spring-tx-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar  
spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar  

cxf-2.4.0.jar  
cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-2.4.0.jar  

jsr173_api-1.0.jar  
jsr311-api-0.6.jar
```

Comment: Could you add your project dependencies?

Comment: @hasnae - Project dependencies are added.